# Error faced during Spark Installation on Ubuntu

Tags: apache-spark

I have followed the following steps during Spark installation on Ubuntu and am facing an error.

Steps followed:

1. tar xvf scala-2.10.6.tgz
2. Then I move this folder to: sudo mv scala-2.10.6 /usr/local/scala-2.10
3. gedit ~/.bashrc
4. Add the Path variable : export PATH = $PATH:/usr/local/scala/bin
5. Check if scala is installed by : scala -version
6. same steps followed for installing Spark-1.6.2.tgz
7. source ~/.bashrc
8. spark-shell

---

As soon i run this "spark-shell" i run into this error: 
ls: cannot access '/usr/local/spark/assembly/target/scala-2.10 : No such file or directory
Failed to find spark assembly in /usr/local/spark/assembly/target/scala-2.10
you need to Build spark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In step #6 you were downloading source code of spark-1.6.2. But for spark installation you need pre-built spark package.

So to get built spark package either you have to build it from source code you downloaded or you need to download pre-built spark package from [spark-downloads page](https://spark.apache.org/downloads.html). In this page you will see step 2 as `Choose a package type:` where you need to select pre-built spark package.

Comment: Thank you so much ! But i would like to add this that #Spark has just added its latest download tar which is 2.0.0 and the [Choose a package type:](http://spark.apache.org/downloads.html) already has the deafult as "Prebuilt for Hadoop 2.7 and later" and it worked out for me.

Comment: Wow that's great news :)  I've been waiting for that (`2.0.0`) from last few months.  Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 0):

It might be your spark-assembly.*.jar not generated try to rebuild your spark and check again.